# Hibernate / MySQL LockTimeoutException when using Optimistic Locking

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

We are running the latest version of Hibernate 4 and `MySQL`. All of our Hibernate entities have a version field annotated with **@Version** since we use Optimistic Locking across the board. Nowhere in the application do we use Pessimistic Locking. My understanding was that `LockTimeoutExceptions` can occur when using Pessimistic Locking, however, we are getting these every so often even though we don't use this locking strategy.

In this particular scenario we have an executor service with a thread pool of size 1. When the users perform certain actions, we create notifications for other users. We delegate this notification creation to the executor service. These notifications can take some time to create so we do it this way so the user doesn't have to sit and wait for notification creation to complete. We use a single sized thread pool so that we don't have notifications being processed multiple times, etc. What we wanted was for these operations to rather queue and run sequentially. Each thread starts a single transaction, creates all the necessary notifications and the commits said transaction and closes the entity manager.

The stack trace for the exception we get is below. Any ideas why we would get a lock in a scenario such as the above? I don't understand it.

```
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    2015-10-08 01:27:52,195 ERROR [NotificationPublishingRunnable] : could not execute statement
    javax.persistence.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapLockException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1812)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1715)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1206)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.DB.merge(171bcc9:315)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.repositories.AbstractRepository.merge(171bcc9 ---------------:158)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.services.notification.EmployeeNotificationCRUDServiceSupport.createEmployeeNotification(171bcc9 remotes/origin/11_9 ---------------:97)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.services.notification.EmployeeNotificationCRUDServiceSupport.createEmployeeNotifications(171bcc9 remotes/origin/11_9 ---------------:75)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.services.notification.EmployeeNotificationCreatorSupport.createEmployeeNotifications(171bcc9 remotes/origin/11_9 -----------:80)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.notification.handler.NotificationHandlerManagerSupport.createNotificationsFromRequest(171bcc9 remotes/origin/11_9 ----------:233)
        at za.co.bsg.ems.server.runnable.notification.NotificationPublishingRunnable.run(171bcc9 remotes/origin/11_9 -------:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$1.convert(MySQLDialect.java:447)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:251)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208
```

Comment: [@brent777] did you ever find a solution to this problem? We are having the exact same problem.

Comment: @AndrewKew unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and it was because I had begun a transaction and didn't commit it, and then started another transaction.

Committing that first transaction fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You annotate all your entities with @Version :  This mean you want to use optimistic locking. The Optimistic locking is managed by the EntityManger, DAO or Repository.

Here you are using a preparedstatement to do your database request. So you are using a pessimistic locking which is a default features of some database. This is the reason you have the LockTimeoutException.

Comment: this answer is not helpful at all it mainly repeats what I already said in my question. Also Optimistic Locking is being used throughout the application, it is not falling back to pessimistic locking because of a "database default" as you suggest. I know this because we also receive OptimisticLockExceptions under other circumstances for this same entity.

Comment: Brent777 i don't know if i understand your question. You say ( in your title ) you have a LockTimeOutException while using Optimistic Locking. My answer stated that you're not using optimistic locking but pessimistic locking since you are using PreparedStatement. If not what is your question ?

Comment: My question is how is it possible to get a LockTimeoutException in an OptimisticLocking environment. As I said in my previous comment, I don't believe that pessimistic locking is being used just because prepared statements are involved. Then why would I get OptimisticLockExceptions for the same entity? Why would it sometimes be optimistic and sometimes pessimistic when all my queries are written in exactly the same way and executed via the Entity Manager as named queries? What is your reference for prepared statements using pessimistic locking even if I have specific Version fields everywhere?

Comment: Could you provide the code which makes the request please ?